# Windows Batch File - Recursive Looping Through sub-directories, ffmeg

Tags: recursion, subdirectory, file-move

I have found a wonderful BAT-file that is very effective in converting MKV to MP4

@echo on
CD /D %~dp0
for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c copy "%%~nf.mp4"
pause

It runs from a Mainfolder and looks into all subfolder and do the conversion automatically without any intervention.

Only issue is that it also moves the newly creted MP4 to Mainfolder where the BAT-file is

How can I edit the BAT-file to stop moving the MP4 to Mainfolder?

---

StartCondition:
C:\
├───MainFolder

- MKVtoMP4.bat
  │
  └───────SubFolder
  - Movie.mkv

Result after running BAT-file:
C:\
├───MainFolder

- MKVtoMP4.bat
- Movie.mp4
  │
  └───────SubFolder
  - Movie.mkv

WANTED Result:
C:\
├───MainFolder

- MKVtoMP4.bat
  │
  └───────SubFolder
  - Movie.mkv
  - Movie.mp4

Read through some thread in Stackoverflow but did not find anything that could help out